# Roboelectric java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, junit, robolectric, android-testing

I'm trying to run roboelectric on my project (with multiple Android library projects) and i keep getting this error when i try running the test project with a simple string check.

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.newInstanceOf(RobolectricInternals.java:33)
>     at org.robolectric.Robolectric.newInstanceOf(Robolectric.java:348)
>     at org.robolectric.Robolectric.newInstanceOf(Robolectric.java:355)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.registerBroadcastReceivers(ShadowApplication.java:121)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.bind(ShadowApplication.java:110)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:136)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:430)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.newInstanceOf(RobolectricInternals.java:25)

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.util.Log.secD(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)  libs dependency version mismatch?

Comment: Ok so i will post that as an answer so if somebody gets the same they would refer it later on rather than reading comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.util.Log.secD(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;) Is the error that you are getting.

It seems you have library (dependency) version mismatch?